# How to expose Hystrix's circuit breaker status through JMX

Tags: java, jmx, hystrix

I've been looking for a tutorial on how to expose Hystrix's circuit breaker status on JMX. I just found out an API for exposing metrics (e.g counters, gauges, etc) using `hystrix-servo-metrics-publisher`.

Is it possible to expose circuit breaker status on JMX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution, just start this code:

```
HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerMetricsPublisher(
    HystrixServoMetricsPublisher.getInstance());
```

After this you'll see the metrics on JMX in `com.netlix.servo`.

Obs: The information will be available on JMX only after the first server request.

Comment: The question is about `status` but for those need to change hystrix configs in runtime: add `-Darchaius.dynamicPropertyFactory.registerConfigWithJMX=true` to your VM options. Read further [here](https://groups.google.com/g/hystrixoss/c/-g21YBTA9l4).