# How to find the number of active threads in a hystrix thread pool?

Tags: threadpool, java-threads, hystrix

I am trying to finetune hystrix threadpool core size and max size. For that I need to know and plot the number of active threads at anytime in the pool. Is there a way to do so?

Is this the right way?

```
HystrixThreadPoolKey hystrixThreadPoolKey = new HystrixThreadPoolKey() {
            @Override
            public String name() {
                return threadPoolKey;
            }
        };
HystrixThreadPoolMetrics hystrixThreadPoolMetrics = HystrixThreadPoolMetrics.getInstance(hystrixThreadPoolKey);
log.info("Hystrix active threads: {}", hystrixThreadPoolMetrics.getCurrentActiveCount().toString());
```

I am not sure because when I use this I get active thread count as 0, when the corePoolSize setting is 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine (after putting a null check for the time till no request is made). But the right way should be to use Netflix's servo.

[Netflix Announcement](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/announcing-servo-ab229fde8c9f)

[How to Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324978/how-to-expose-hystrixs-circuit-breaker-status-through-jmx)

Quoting some part from the announcement:

*Servo is designed to make it easy for developers to export metrics from their application code, register them with JMX, and publish them to external monitoring systems*

(Also active thread pool size can be less than the core size)